# What's the simplest way to execute scripts on two computers on the same network?

Tags: bloomberg, thomson-reuters-eikon

I have two PCs in my office, one with Reuters Eikon and one with Bloomberg.

I have a program that use both of their APIs for downloading financial data (Bloomberg has some additional fields I need and Eikon gives unlimited data), but I've been struggling with finding a way to communicate with both PCs using a third device.

They have their vendor limitations: the Bloomberg API only works a Bloomberg terminal, while the Eikon API requires a running and logged Eikon instance. For security reasons I'm cautious about opening up ports and I would like to find a way to execute scripts on my local network. I mostly use Python.

So, what's the best way to execute scripts on two computers on the same network?

Comment: You could save the data on a shared folder or a database, but that would very likely be a breach of your Bloomberg licence (I don't know the terms of Reuters licence).

Comment: Have you looked at Ansible? It uses SSH to run scripts and you can restrict it only be one particular user... What OS's are the terminals on.